# Not Access to Confusion Matrix in SVM.SVC.score Scikit-learn Python

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn, svm, pca

I used SVM.SVC function to classify. But when I wanted to calculate the weighted and unweighted average accuracy I couldn't access the confusion matrix. Because of svm.SVC.score only provides a classifier accuracy percentage. How can I calculate WAR and UAR?

you can find part of my script below :

'''

```
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    scaler.fit(trainX)
    trainXsc = scaler.transform(trainX)
    testXsc = scaler.transform(testX)

    pca = KernelPCA(n_components=j, kernel="sigmoid", random_state=1)  

    pca.fit(trainXsc)     # fit pca kernel with train data

    trainXtr    = pca.transform(trainXsc) # transform FV with PCA and dimension reduction
    testXtr     = pca.transform(testXsc)

    svmObject   = svm.SVC(C=2.0, kernel='rbf', degree=3, gamma='scale', coef0=0.0, shrinking=True,
                  probability=False, tol=0.001, cache_size=200, class_weight=None,
                  verbose=False, max_iter=-1, decision_function_shape='ovo', random_state=None)
                                        # SVM Kernel Function

    svmObject.fit(trainXtr, trainY)      # train SVM kernel with train FV

    result = svmObject.score(testXtr, testY)
```

'''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the `score` method on your trained model, you should use the `predict` method.

You can then pass the results into the confusion matrix function from sklearn:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
y_pred = svmObject.predict(X)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=sample_weight,
                      labels=labels, normalize=normalize)
```

There is also a nice function called [**plot_confusion_matrix**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html#sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix):

```
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix

plot_confusion_matrix(svmObject, testXtr, testY)
plt.show()
```